# visual studio 2010 CTP expiration work around

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I downloaded the VS2010 CTP from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=922B4655-93D0-4476-BDA4-94CF5F8D4814&displaylang=en

It took a while to download and install naturally and after running it in Virtual PC I was disappoint to see that it expired already even though it was still available for download.

I then started to research on what I needed to do to get it to work beyond it's Jan 1 2009 expiration date. I looked at this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2007/11/28/disabling-time-synchronization-under-virtual-pc-2007.aspx

..But the instructions mention to modify  setting in the VMC file.

The problem is, I did a search of the file and there is no such tag in it.

I tried to set back my clock in my host system before launching VPC but that didn't work either.

Any suggestion anyone? I'm wondering why MS is leaving up the 2010 CTP download page if there is no point in installing it. Is there a more up to date version available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those instructions do work - you have to insert the extra tag into the config file; it's not there to start with.

I suspect the reason they're leaving it up is so that people can download it. :)

Before re-attempting the setup, you'll probably need to start again with the VM in a state where it has never been run, so you should unpack it from the download files again.

Answer (score 3):

[Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4 Beta 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dd582936.aspx)

I'm not sure of its expiration date.

Comment: Yea, the beta was released last week, and is about 9 months newer that the CTP.